# Pass PHP Variable To JavaScript And Use Alert To Display

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting the below to pass the value in my php variable to JavaScript, but I never have the alert display on screen.  What is the proper way to do such?

**PHP**

```
<?php  $date = '20170101'; ?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var datestring = <? php echo $date; ?>;
var year = datestring.substring(0,4);
alert(year);
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3ed6opj3/

The desired result that I want to display in the alert is 2017 - the answers below to this point have all been showing `<? p`

Comment: This is giving me <? p as the alert, I want it to show 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add " on between the php script

```
var datestring = "<?php echo $date; ?>";
```

Comment: That produces <? p - my desired result is 2017

Comment: try again on the up code i already edited, previously already space between <? and php.

Comment: Yeah on jsfiddle cant change to php language, you can running on your local machine for trying

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes

```
<?php echo "\"".$date."\""; ?>;
```